# How to concat each element of an array with the string

Tags: javascript

in the html : `<span class="cart-prize">30.00</span>`

```
const total = [];
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-prize'); //item price displaying on the cart when cart popups


 items.forEach(function(item)
 {               
     total.push(parseFloat(item.textContent)).toFixed(2); 
 });



const totalMoney = total.reduce((accumulator, EachArrayValue) 
  => accumulator + EachArrayValue); 

items.forEach((each) => each = "$"+ each.textContext);

document.getElementById("totalMoney").textContent = 
"$"+totalMoney; //works ok

document.getElementById("itemTotal").textContent = 
total.length + " items"; //works ok
```

after summing up all the price elements in the total array with the reduce method here I tried to concat "$" string with the each textcontent of "cart-prize":

`items.forEach((each) => each = each.textContext + "$");`

But not succeed.Only float numbers display on the cart without dollar sign

I couldn't figure out where I've made a mistake. Is there anthing wrong with this method : `items.forEach((each) => each = "$" + each.textContext);`

Comment: Why are you trying to overwrite `each`? Should that not be `each.textContext` to begin with …?

Comment: do you refer to the `each` in the left-hand side of the assignment  ?

Answer (score 1):

you're loosing the reference to the original `each` object with this override

```
items.forEach((each) => each = "$"+ each.textContext);
```

you should try with a standard for loop

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i] = "$"+ items[i].textContext;
}
```

Comment: thank for you comment but that didn't work either.. element still stays the same without sign

Answer (score 0):

The problem using `items.forEach((each) => each = each.textContext + "$");` is this only iterates between the `items` array without create a new one.

Instead of using `forEach` you could use `map`, which creates a new array, an assign to the `items` again like the example bellow:

```js
let items = [{textContent: "example1"}, {textContent: "example2"}];

items = items.map((object) => {
    object.textContent = "$" + object.textContent;
    return object;
});

console.log(items);
```

For find [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-map-vs-foreach-f38111822c0f) more information about the difference between `map` and `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

misorude is correct in his/her comment. All you need to do is use `each.textContent` instead of `each` inside of your forEach loop.

```
items.forEach((each) => each.textContent = "&"+each.textContent);
```

Comment: yes. That was true. Silly but I was sure that I had already tried what he says couple of times before posting  here.  Only now I realized that I haven't actually.